# SQL Dataset to JSON

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, json

Alright I have been trying to figure this out and I read the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) page on the JavaScriptSerializer. However, I still can't figure out how to get this to work on an asp.net page. I want to convert my dataset into a json string so I can graph it using FLOT(graphing tool)

---

THIS MADE IT WORK THANKS FOR YOUR HELP GUYS: this is in vb.net for future people

```
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization
```

....

```
Dim myObject = dataset.GetXml()
Dim jsonString = (New JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(myObject)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reference the assembly System.Web.Extensions.dll and then do this:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

....

var myObject = ... your stuff ...
var jsonString = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(myObject);
```

Check out the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) for more info.

Comment: You know that jsonString is going to be a String. Why not just use string instead of var? I love the var keyword in C# but it is making some people lazy and some code less readable. Please don't encourage this bad practice.

Comment: I'm sorry but that's just very wrong in my opinion. You gain all the benefit from having a type system even if you dont write the types explicitly. Making the code readable is not about sprinkling types everywhere, it's about giving meaningful names to things (obviously "jsonString" is a perfect anti-example, but the OP can choose a name based on his context). Have you every used a language where everything (even function arguments and return values) are implicit? Have you ever used a dynamic language? How can we use languages like that when they encourage bad practice?

Comment: A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo'.

Comment: Or, a shorter version: Types are for the compiler. Names are for humans.

Comment: is the error i get my code looks like 
        da.Fill(ds)
        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        GridView1.DataBind()
        da.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Mapped)

        Dim jsonString = New JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ds)
        TextBox1.Text = jsonString

        conn.Close()

Comment: @NEWprogrammer: what kind of object are you trying to serialize? i.e, what is ds? (been a long time since I did any asp.net sql coding)

Comment: @Kenneth: I can't get this out of my head, it's just too much :) How can you love the "var" keyword if you think it shouldn't be used when you know the type? C# is a statically typed language, you ALWAYS know the type (except if it's anonymous). We should probably avoid the keyword altogether then. And while we're at it, anonymous types are kind of bad too, because we don't have a type to describe them.

Comment: @Jakob ds is my dataset that i am trying to put into json

Comment: @NEWprogrammer datasets always have circular references. You have to make sure that either child or parent properties (all of them!) is set to access "Internal", in dataset designer. That way, serializer won't see it. That's what I always do when I serialize datasets (Typed Datasets or Entity Framework items).

Comment: how would i do that? I am sorry this is my first time having to do this.

Comment: open dataset designer, click on connector between two tables, and look in the properties window

Comment: the problem is i didn't make a data-set in the designer, i did it manually by code.

Comment: I got it to work but I am stuck trying to parse the json string using jquery

Comment: I'd gladly help you with that too, but it should be a new question :)

Comment: @MyHeadHurts - Could you share how you got datable serialized, when datatable is generated in code? I am having the same circular reference problem when converting datatable to json.

Answer (score 2):

I did the following when I was working on a Project using PlotKit. I create a webservice to return the data and set the response format to Jason...this was while ago...should also work in 3.5

Here is a sample

```
<WebMethod()> _
    <Script.Services.ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet:=True, ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
      Public Function GetSales(ByVal a As String) As Generic.List(Of Sale)
        Dim _conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connstr)
        Dim _dr As SqlDataReader
        Try
            Dim _cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("select * from sales", _conn)
            _conn.Open()
            _dr = _cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

            If _dr.HasRows Then
                Dim s As Sale
                Dim c As New Generic.List(Of Sale)
                While _dr.Read
                    s = New Sale
                    With s
                        .Month = _dr("monthname")
                        .TheSale = _dr("sale")
                    End With
                    c.Add(s)
                End While

                Return c
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            _conn.Close()
        End Try

              End Function

End Class
```

Here is the object class...notice I am serializing the object.

```
<Serializable()> _
Public Class Sale
    Private _month As String
    Private _sale As String

    Public Property Month() As String
        Get
            Return _month
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _month = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property TheSale() As String
        Get
            Return _sale
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _sale = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), and this article on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static string DStoJSON(DataSet ds)
{
   StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();

   foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
   {
       json.Append("{");

       int i = 0;
       int colcount = dr.Table.Columns.Count;

       foreach (DataColumn dc in dr.Table.Columns)
       {
           json.Append("\"");
           json.Append(dc.ColumnName);
           json.Append("\":\"");
           json.Append(dr[dc]);
           json.Append("\"");

           i++;
           if (i < colcount) json.Append(",");

       }
       json.Append("\"}");
       json.Append(",");
   }
   return json.ToString();
}
```

Probably most useful to you is the dataset loop instead of the `stringbuilder`. You could loop these into an object, then use the javascript `serializer` library.

Or even better, if you are using asp.net mvc, you can just do this:

```
return Json(List<myobject>, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

but this way is quick & easy! -- I didn't quite test this! the appended comma might be wrong (or code can be improved) and the final row comma needs to be handled

I use the mvc way & never looked back :)

Comment: could you help me convert this into vb.net, or is it not possible

Comment: why would you implement your own serializer when there's one in .NET?

Comment: i basically say that! -- this is just if he doesn't want to use an object!

Comment: can you help me parse the json string?